# How to view incoming data stream Gatling.IO

Tags: gatling

I'm wondering how I can print (on screen or to file) the incoming data stream after making a get call with Gatling.IO.  I'd like to see what's in the body to verify if the data I'm getting is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In logback.xml (which is present if you use the bundle or the Maven archetype), uncomment lines 12 and 13.
2. In your protocol configuration, add `.disableResponseChunksDiscarding`. By default, Gatling discards the bodies unless they're needed (e.g. checks) as an optimization.